# How to exclude `*.test.ts` from Vite 5

Tags: vite, rollup

I'm using Vite 5. I want to exclude my `*.test.ts` files from bundling by Vite5.

Here is my `vite.config.js`:

```js
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import {resolve} from "path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {
    const prod = mode === "prod";

    return {
        plugins: [react(), dts(), tsconfigPaths()],
        build: {
            lib: {
                entry: resolve(__dirname, "./src/App.tsx"),
                formats: ["es"],
            },
            rollupOptions: {
                external: [
                    "react",
                    "react-dom",
                ],
            },
            sourcemap: !prod,
        },
    };
});
```

I've tried:

- `rollupOptions.external: ["**.test.ts"]`
- `rollupOptions.external: [src => src.indexOf("*.test.ts") !== -1]`

but it doesn't work.

How can I exclude that files?

Comment: What makes you think they're currently included? Unless your tests are imported by the production code, which would be odd, they wouldn't generally be found from the entrypoint.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know exactly whether `temp.test.ts` is included or not, but `temp.test.d.ts` file is created in `dist/`. This is why I think `temp.test.ts` is included.

Comment: Then maybe it's just _that plugin_ including it - what's in `tsconfig.json`, similarly have you looked at [its config options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-dts#options).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ahh.. You are right! Thank you. Thanks to you, I solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that `temp.test.d.ts` file was included in `dist/`. I thought it because of Vite bundling option. However it's not a problem about Vite but `dts` plugin. (Because creating `d.ts` file is `dts`'s responsibility)

So I solved it by changing the config to:

```js
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import {resolve} from "path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(({mode}) => {
    const prod = mode === "prod";

    return {
        plugins: [react(), dts({exclude: "**/*.test.ts"}), tsconfigPaths()], // the key change is here
        build: {
            lib: {
                entry: resolve(__dirname, "./src/App.tsx"),
                formats: ["es"],
            },
            rollupOptions: {
                external: [
                    "react",
                    "react-dom",
                ],
            },
            sourcemap: !prod,
        },
    };
});
```